# Trying to write function map() getting error IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, function, dictionary, python-3.4

I'm trying to write function map() getting error IndexError: list index out of range

```
     def map1(fn, a):
         i = 0
         b = []
         while i != len(a):
             print(len(a))
             i += 1
             b.append(fn(a[i]))
         return b
```

with working function

```
    def translate(x):
        dicti = {"merry": "god", "christmas": "jul", "and": "och", "happy": "gott", "new": "nytt", "year": "år"}
        return dicti[x]
```

got the error

```
     IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please post a full stacktrace of the `IndexError` so that it is possible to see where it occurs. What are the arguments to `map1()`  that produce the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increment `i` before accessing `a`. In the last iteration, `i` is `len(a)-1` at the beginning of the loop body, then it is incremented to `len(a)`, but this is just outside the valid index range. To fix it, you have to increment after the access:

```
while i != len(a):
    b.append(fn(a[i]))
    i += 1
```

However, an improved way to do this, is to use `range`, which produces the correct values for `i`  for you automatically:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    b.append(fn(a[i]))
```

An even better way is to iterate over the entries of `a` directly:

```
for x in a:
    b.append(fn(x))
```

An *even better* way is to use a list comprehension:

```
b = [fn(x) for x in a]
```

Comment: That worked when I used it, although I'm not sure how to set it up with the last line of code you posted...

Comment: Instead of: `def map1(fn, a): b = []; ...; return b`, you do: `def map1(fn, a): b = [fn(x) for x in a]; return b`, or simply `def map1(fn, a): return [fn(x) for x in a]`

Answer (score 1):

You where increasing `i` before using it.

```
def map1(fn, a):
         i = 0
         b = []
         while i != len(a):
             print(len(a))

             b.append(fn(a[i]))
             i += 1
         return b

def translate(x):
        dicti = {"merry": "god", "christmas": "jul", "and": "och", "happy": "gott", "new": "nytt", "year": "ar"}
        return dicti[x]

map1(translate, ["merry", "and"])
```